# Ubuntu base64 encoded string ends with "o=" instead of apparently correct "=="

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, base64, padding

In the instructions on [this OAuth protocol](https://www.polar.com/accesslink-api/?http#token-endpoint), you can see that the example base64 encoding of "12345:verySecret" is

"MTIzNDU6dmVyeVNlY3JldA=="

The problem is, when I run `echo 12345:verySecret | base64`I get

"MTIzNDU6dmVyeVNlY3JldAo="

During actual authentication I was banging my head against a wall until I realized I needed to change the second to last "o" character into "=" in my own encoded *client_id:client_secret* string. But why?

Comment: echo might be inducing newline character, try with -n flag with echo `echo -n 12345:secret | base64`

Comment: That appears to change the ending quite a bit: "MTIzNDU6c2VjcmV0"

Comment: @BenOgorek because it wasn't the exact same string. Just add the `-n` option to your own sample.

Comment: @Evert, fair point. OK now that this is returning the exact string with "==" at the end, who wants to write it up for an accepted answer?

Comment: Since @crack_iT had the (essentially) correct answer first, they should be the one to get the credit (if they want it).

Comment: ok, I'll add answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

echo inducing newline character, try with -n flag with echo

```
echo -n 12345:secret | base64
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **echo** as stated in the accepted answer, but you have to use the -n switch. If you use **printf** instead, you can eliminate the -n switch.

I mention this because **echo** gets users in all sorts of inadvertent trouble with the various switches it can employ, and in most cases, **printf** will give you what you really need without the gotcha's, this being a prime example.